# bash + ftp: File is empty on upload

Tags: html, linux, bash, ftp

I have written a bash script to update a page on my company's website. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby final_07.rb

HOST=ftp.website.com
USER=username
PASSWD=password

ftp -n -v $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
delete warehouse.html.old
rename warehouse.html warehouse.html.old
put warehouse.html warehouse.html

EOF
```

It runs the Ruby script just fine. It connects to the FTP just fine. It even renames the old file just fine. However, when it "uploads", I just get a file named 'warehouse.html' that is 0 bytes - it's totally empty. I checked, and the source file is fine. When I manually upload with FileZilla, it works just fine, too. So, what gives?

Here's the log from my terminal window:

```
john@starfire:~/code/ruby/idealm_db_parser/final$ ./update_script_02.sh
Connected to www.website.com.
220 FTP Service
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
331 Password required for user.
230 User user logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
250 DELE command successful
350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name.
250 Rename successful
local: warehouse.html remote: warehouse.html
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for warehouse.html
226 Transfer complete.
221
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, if that helps.

Comment: Does the .old file look correct? Can you view the file permissions AND directory permissions on the remote machine? Make sure they are OK. (Zero file *is* weird ;-)!

Comment: Permissions. You might be on to something. I am still pretty unfamiliar with how *nix handles permissions, so I wouldn't be surprised. I'll be to work in an hour or so - I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: And are sending and receiving machines both Ubuntu. Different OS's will have different Ftp clients with sometimes radically different option and processing.

Comment: New strangeness: When I run the script, it zeros the warehouse.html file on my side, not on the FTP's side. I have no idea why. Anyway, I removed the `delete` and `rename` lines, and it's working now. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it sorted. I removed the lines:

```
delete warehouse.html.old
rename warehouse.html warehouse.html.old
```

and that seemed to do the trick. For some reason, apparently the script was zeroing the warehouse.html file on MY computer, then uploading that.

Thanks to everyone who helped, though.

Comment: so you don't care what happens to the existing html.old OR that you won't be keeping a backup copy? (Maybe that is OK, but then ...)

Comment: It should be fine. The HTML is dynamically generated with a script I wrote from a file that's exported from our database, and I keep copies of the exports - so if something goes wrong, it would make more sense to regenerate the HTML from the database export.

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.

Comment: @Otaku Thanks. I already tried that - I'll not be able to until tomorrow, but I will then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to

- switch to asci mode before you put your file
- use passive ftp mode for transfering the file